# Get latest entry of a specific column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (called `btB`) with multiple entries where I need to get the ones with a certain `beitragID`. Almost all fields with a specific `beitragID` are the same, except for the `bID`.

```
     bID | title  | beitragID
---------|--------|-------------
102      | blabla1 | 1013
1054     | blabla2 | 1013
1678     | blabla3 | 1013
104      | blublu1 | 1213
1058     | blublu2 | 1213
1668     | blublu3 | 1213
...
```

Since there is no field in which the creation date is noted and I assume there is no SQL functionality to detect the most recent entry without a date field, I want to get the row with the highest `bID`.

I'm struggeling to get the correct SQL query. This is what I got so far:

```
SELECT title FROM btB WHERE beitragID = '1013' or beitragID = '1213'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build a group you can use the aggregate function `max()` to get the highest value of each group

```
select  t1.*
from btB t1
join
(
   SELECT max(bID) as bID, beitragID
   FROM btB 
   WHERE beitragID in (1013, 1213)
   group by beitragID
) t2 on t1.bid = t2.bid and t1.beitragID = t2.beitragID
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, bur if I do it like this, I somehow get all six entries as result.

Comment: I doubt that. Is your example data different from your real data?

Comment: I guess the problem is, that the `title` column has in fact also different data for each `bID`. If I use another column where the values are all the same it works. So could you maybe update the query, that I only get the `title` of the highest `bID` for each `beitragID`. I'll update my sample structure.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for staying with me on this, I appreciate that very much! :)